# How to use IN() clause with List in JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to query with `JdbcTemplate` using a list to match:

```
List foos = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from foo where name IN (?)", 
    new Object[] { Arrays.asList("foo1", "foo2", "foo3")}, 
    new FooMapper()
);
```

Result: the database columns are not matched, even though the `name` column equal the string `foo1`. Why?

If possible with `JdbcTemplate` without named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<String> names = ...;

MapSqlParameterSource fooParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();
fooParams.addValue("names", names);

List<Foo> foo = getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name IN (:names)",
     fooParams, getRowMapper());
```

Comment: Is there a solution without having to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and  `MapSqlParameterSource`?

Comment: Yes.

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); //add 
Map namesMap = Collections.singletonMap("names", names); and then pass namesMap in your query params @membersound

Comment: So but then I'd still have to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`? I'm looking for a solution with `JdbcTemplate` directly, if possible.

Comment: No. It just replaces `new Object[] { Arrays.asList("foo1", "foo2", "foo3")},` in your sample with namesMap which is java map.

Comment: Well, `JdbcTemplate.query(sql, Collections.singletonMap(..), new FooMapper());`seems to be invalid. There is no query method in the normal JdbcTemplate that can take those args!